# Android handle thread with dynamic activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm developing an Android network application. I want to have one worker thread that will handle all incoming data over a socket). The thread will be active all the time.

I can start the thread from one of my activities, but how to handle it after the activity is changed?

By handle, I mean how to interact with the thread (passing data from thread to current UI or sending data to the thread from the current UI).

I'm looking at `AsyncTask` but I'm not sure if it can be used with my situation

Comment: You definetly need to use a service. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: @VM I'm looking at your link. I think I'm going to have to work on it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look at one of two models.

The first is to use a Service which will "own" the socket connection. The second is to spin up a HandlerThread to "own" the connection. Which you choose is based on what the socket is doing.

If the socket connection contains data that you need to receive, typically stuff you'll cache locally, then a Service is more appropriate, because running in a Service means that your work will get done eventually. On the other hand if you are doing something like downloading an image that is only ever displayed in your UI, then using a raw HandlerThread might be the right choice. The reasoning here is that the moment your UI goes away your socket connection might as well be closed. Put another way, the choice is based on how ephemeral the use of the data is.

Now, if you're going to use a Service, please, please, use an IntentService which will handle the grotesque details of shutting down the Service at the appropriate time. It will also put your processing code on the correct Thread. **A command sent to a Service by default runs on the main/UI thread of your application.** An IntentService marshals the work to a background thread.

If you're going to use a HandlerThread, I would make a class that extends HandlerThread and then use the singleton pattern to handle accessing the same HandlerThread from any Activity.

One important question to ask yourself though is when your Service or HandlerThread shuts down. When is the work done and how is this signaled? Is it just when no more data arrives? When your apps UI goes into the background?

Comment: My socket will handle incoming socket data as long as my program is running. I think I really need to look at Service. I found some documents about Service and IntentService. I'm going to go with IntentService as you said. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement I suggest that you create and use JAX-WS or JAX-RS.
Here are a lot of examples which fully describe that. In that case you can use AsyncTask easily. 
Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785205/android-rest-api-connection/20785431#20785431), I suppose that this solution can meet your needs.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with this:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(
  @Override
  public void run () {

   while (true /* or your breaking condition */) {
   //Here you put your socket algorithm

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run () {
         //Here you put every change you want to do on UI thread
       }
     } 
     //This is necessary to reduce process consumption
      try { 
        Thread.sleep(30L);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }));
t.start();
```

### How to know on which UI

Each handler you create is attached to the class on which it was created.
As you can see here [Android | Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

For example, if you have a class that extends Activity and you create a Handler there, it'll work on that UI thread.

Comment: I assume that this code is executed in an activity. What if I change the activity? Will the socket algorithm work? and how to know what UI I'm working on.

Thanks

Comment: This code can go either in an Activity or a Service.
What you mean with "change the Activity" ?
You mean changing to another Activity or Close the application?
In either case, the process will be discontinued when Android destroys the Application. 
If you want to keep it running, you better choose a Service instead of an Activity

Comment: There seems to be a misconception here that two different Activity classes have different UI threads, they do not. A process has a single UI thread (more appropriately called the "main thread"). All Activity instances in a given Android package share the same event loop running on the main Thread. A Handler has no direct attachment to an Activity class unless it is an inner class of that Activity.

Comment: Also, you're really abusing the Threading model here. There's no reason to busy wait to way you're doing. Unless you really know you need to, don't sleep in a loop, let the scheduler determine if you should run or not. Better than Thread.sleep() is to just use a HandlerThread and post a message in the future to run the next iteration of whatever you want to do. Further, if the I/O thread is calling socket.read() its likely to yield the processor anyway as it waits for data to arrive.

Comment: @cyngus, very well explained. That concept of sleep a thread inside a loop was a doubt that I used to have. But I found that solution a long time ago. That worked for me and made me lazy to search a better solution. About the Handler, `When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it` is what We see in the documentation. That's what I meant. Maybe I should've explained myself better.

Comment: I might be overly sensitive on the issue of what Handlers belong to. Its easy for people to get the idea that each Activity or Service has its own event loop, which is not true, but could easily appear to be the case until someone codes in a bug and it because very clear that something does not match expectations.